# DataGridView uses over 4Gb memory with 10 rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, memory, datagridview

I have problem with DatagridView.
I'm developing Windows forms application with VisualStudio 2019/VisualBasic Application target is NET 4.8 framework.
Problem is REALLY huge memory usage. **DataGridView takes over 4Gb memory with 10 rows of data!**
Memory is allocated when I set datasource for datagridview.
Memory amount do not change much, if there is 10 rows or 1000 rows of data.
Grid uses Datatable as datasource, Datatable gets filled from SQL Server.

```
MySqlDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataset) ' 
MyGrid.DataSource = MyDataset.Tables(0) ' This row causes 1.5s delay in time, and consumes over 4Gb memory
```

Visualstudio diagnostic tool shows this memory allocation, but I cannot see it in heap view.

If Datagridview allocates some extra memory in advance, How I can adjust or disable it?
Tried GC.Collect but it do not help, no memory freed.  I do not notice this before.
What is changed with my development computer, I buy more memory, Total of 16Gb now.

Comment: The DatatGridView Control doesn't *take over 4Gb memory with 10 rows of data*, at all. Do you see this memory usage grow over time? When? Each time you fill the DataSet? How often this happens? Are you disposing of the disposable objects used to query your database? Are you using Graphics objects? Drawing stuff on controls? Using Graphics object from the Project's Resources? Other stuff you should be disposing but you don't?

Comment: 4GB is consumed in 1.5s like I said. When I close dialog, memory freed normally.

Comment: Well, you should post the code used in this Dialog, along with any object created when an Instance of this Dialog is created. -- Note that when you create a Form and use `ShowDialog()` to show it, you need to call `[FormDialog].Dispose()` on it right after. -- This all has nothing to do with a DataGridView.

Comment: I tried comment that row out, in that case there is normal memory usage. Tried set breakpoint to that row, before it's executed, only 32Mb memory is consumed for whole program. after I press Shift+F8 (Step Over) 4.5GB is consumed. I see memory usage in Visual studio Diagnostic tools window and in Windows TaskManager->performance page. All memory is freed normally after I close dialog that contains this datagrid. Looks like there is no memory leak, just really big usage.

Comment: This do not have nothing to do with form itself. Like I said. Datagridview.datasource=dataset.table(0) causes memory usage.  Of course I dispose dialog after use.  Memory is freed normally after I close dialog.  I make try with older framework version tomorrow, let see what happens.  This dialog is my old code, been used succesfully about 10 years in other applications.  For this new, I made some modifications, like new framework version.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.
Problem is in my developing computer, broken NET framework or something like.
Same application installed to another computer works normally and takes max 35Mb memory.

Comment: Last comment. WIndows Update assistant updated my computer to latest windows version and problem is gone.